# Initialize a property with a function in SwiftUI?

Tags: swift, struct, swiftui

I have a simple SwiftUI view which displays three number positions and a refresh button. The refresh button runs a `pickThree()` function which replaces each number with a random one.

In order to start the view, I need to give each position a starting number, as shown in the `allVals` variable.

I want to start the view with a random number in each position, and not the hard-coded numbers from the `allVals` variable. It seems that I should be able to do this by running the same `pickThree()` refresh function… perhaps by setting it as the value of the `allVals` variable upfront:

```swift
@State var allVals = pickThree()
```

This produces an error:

> Cannot use instance member 'pickThree' within property initializer; property initializers run before 'self' is available

What am I missing here?

```swift
import SwiftUI

struct ThreeCards: View {
    // @State var allVals = pickThree() // PRODUCES ERROR
    @State var allVals = [1,2,3]
    
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            HStack {
                Text(String(allVals[0]))
                Text(String(allVals[1]))
                Text(String(allVals[2]))
            }
            
            Button(action: {
                pickThree()
            }) {
                Text("Refresh")
            }
        }
    }
    
    func pickThree() -> [Int] {
        let one = Int.random(in: 1...3)
        let two = Int.random(in: 1...3)
        let three = Int.random(in: 1...3)
        
        allVals = [one, two, three]
        
        return allVals
    }
}
```

Comment: you can initialize allVals as an empty [int] then call .onAppear() after the closing bracket of one of your stacks and make the ruction call there

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The statement `@State var allVals = pickThree()` implicitly requires `self` to initialize the instance variable `allVals`, but when this happens `self` is not yet available.

There are several approaches.

1. Use static function instead:

This applies when you don't need access to other instance variables.

```
struct ThreeCards: View {
    @State var allVals = ThreeCards.pickThree() 
    
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            HStack {
                Text(String(allVals[0]))
                Text(String(allVals[1]))
                Text(String(allVals[2]))
            }
            
            Button(action: {
                allVals = ThreeCards.pickThree()
            }) {
                Text("Refresh")
            }
        }
    }
    
    static func pickThree() -> [Int] {
        let one = Int.random(in: 1...3)
        let two = Int.random(in: 1...3)
        let three = Int.random(in: 1...3)
        return [one, two, three]
    }
}
```

2. Initialize the instance variable in `init`:

```
struct ThreeCards: View {
    @State var allVals = [Int.random(in: 1...3), Int.random(in: 1...3), Int.random(in: 1...3)]
    
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            HStack {
                Text(String(allVals[0]))
                Text(String(allVals[1]))
                Text(String(allVals[2]))
            }
            
            Button(action: {
                allVals = pickThree()
            }) {
                Text("Refresh")
            }
        }
    }
    
    init() {
        allVals = pickThree()
    }
    
    func pickThree() -> [Int] {
        let one = Int.random(in: 1...3)
        let two = Int.random(in: 1...3)
        let three = Int.random(in: 1...3)
        return [one, two, three]
    }
}
```

3. A much neater one, for this particular purpose:

```
struct ThreeCards: View {
    @State var digits = ["1", "2", "3"].shuffled()
    
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            HStack {
                Text(digits[0])
                Text(digits[1])
                Text(digits[2])
            }
            
            Button(action: {
                digits.shuffle()
            }) {
                Text("Refresh")
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: YES! Your first method works great! Your second method (the one I think I should use) builds fine but returns an error when I run it in the Simulator "_Thread 1: Fatal error: Index out of range_" on the `Text(String(allVals[0]))` line. Any ideas?

Comment: @Sam  oops, sorry. Second one still needs some tweaks to work. I should give `allVals` a default array of ints to avoid `index out of range`.

Comment: Forget about the second one. There is some duplication. I've come up with a third one for your particular context.

Comment: @BenjaminWen Third option is nice and succinct! Still wrapping my head around this SwiftUI stuff. Thanks for your insights.